# Camel Idempotent removeOnFailure for some exception types only

Tags: java, apache-camel

Considering this simple Camel route:

```
from("timer:some timer")
    .bean(someBeanThatProducesLists)
    .split(body()).parallelProcessing()                    . 
        .idempotentConsumer(simple("${body.id}"), myIdempotentRepository)
            .bean(beamThatProcesses)
```

This is working as expected. When an exception occurs in `beamThatProcesses` the key is removed and is re-processed if `someBeanThatProducesLists` returns an entry with the same ID again. 
What I would like is to have

```
onException(MyCustomException.class)
    .maximumRedeliveries(3)
```

And keep the ID in the idempotent repository after the re-deliveries are exhausted, but only for this specific exception, so `removeOnFailure` doesn't really help here.

I browsed through the documentation and also Camel In Action second edition v12, but could not find any way to implement this. I did find that marking exception `handled` does not help.

I could set `removeOnFailure` to false, and then have custom exception handlers that remove it in most exceptions and keep it on custom when retries exhausted, but it's error prone as the idempotent key would have to be computed in multiple places, exceptions can occur anywhere in the route etc.

I guess I could catch the exception in  `beamThatProcesses` and deal with it there, but I'm hoping there is a way to instruct camel to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing something like this in my idempotent repository:

```
    @Override
    public boolean remove(Exchange exchange, Object key) {
        Throwable caught = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Throwable.class);
        if (exchange.getException() == null && caught != null) {
            logger.info("Exception was handled, not removing key");
            return false;
        } else {
            // ... remove the message
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `handled(true)` for that specific `onException` to tell Camel that its okay, so the idempotent repository will see it as okay and do a commit and therefore store the id in the repository.

The `handled(true)` can also accept a `Predicate` so you can evaluate either `true` or `false` if you need even more fine grained control whether to handle or not.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Claus, that would have been my first assumption, but I saw this discussion and your reply there thew me off a bit: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Idempotent-consumer-removeOnFailure-true-and-exception-handling-td5756198.html . I have a custom non transaction idempotent repository, so I just need it not to remove the key, but I guess that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I tested this, and it seems `ExchangeIdempotentRepository.remove` is called even when the Exception is handled.  It's not the clean solution but since this is my own implementation I could check the exchange to see if the exception was handled.